# Query with time parameter Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have database in Google Sheets, Let's say the named sheet is Sheet 12 and Sheet 13. In Sheet 12, I have data in the range `Sheet 12'!A:C` as pictured below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF4Yo.jpg)

Then in Sheet 13, I have data in the range `Sheet 13'!A:C` as pictured below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AELR.jpg)

In Sheet 13 column B, i would like to query data values from Sheet 12 (only column C) by unique combination of Time and Date.

Below is an example of my expected output based on the sample data above.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVWd6.jpg)

Before that, i have created formula but it not worked. Following my formula:

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(QUERY('Sheet 12'!$A$2:C; "Select C WHERE B = date'"&text(A5; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND A <= time'"&text(B1; "hh:mm:ss")&"' AND A >= time'"&text(B2; "hh:mm:ss")&"'  "; 0))))`

Please advise how I can query to correct this sheet. Thankyou

Comment: Share a sample work book or post data as text table so that we can copy and paste.

Comment: ` Remove space from here `&"'  "`

Comment: sorry sir i still understand, which part of formula to remove space of your suggest?

Comment: `=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(QUERY('Sheet 12'!$A$2:C; "Select C WHERE B = date '"&text(A5; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND A <= time '"&text(B1; "hh:mm:ss")&"' AND A >= time '"&text(B2; "hh:mm:ss")&"'"; 0))))`

Comment: the result still #VALUE! sir. Maybe I share link of sheet to your sir if you have any ideas.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y6wJvlxi4WwD4RxpZQ0OpmhhCXCHfjBeZsujiAbQz-w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: See my answer as well as your sample sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following formula-

```
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(QUERY('Sheet 12'!$A$2:C; "Select C WHERE B = date '"&text(A5; "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' AND A >= timeofday '"&text(B1; "hh:mm:ss")&"' AND A <= timeofday '"&text(B2; "hh:mm:ss")&"'"; 0)))
```

You can also use `FILTER()` function. Try-

```
=TOROW(UNIQUE(FILTER('Sheet 12'!C:C;'Sheet 12'!B:B=A5;'Sheet 12'!A:A>=B1;'Sheet 12'!A:A<=B2)))
```

For dynamic spill array, use `MAP()`.

```
=MAP(A5:A6;LAMBDA(x;TOROW(UNIQUE(FILTER('Sheet 12'!C:C;'Sheet 12'!B:B=x;'Sheet 12'!A:A>=B1;'Sheet 12'!A:A<=B2)))))
```

[image]